# Determining equality of sets defined by polynomial inequalities in several variables

Tags: inequality, polynomials, real-algebraic-geometry

Let's say I have two sets $S_1,S_2 \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ each defined by a number of polynomial inequalities.  Is there a computationally feasible way to find whether $S_1 = S_2$?  In particular, is there software available that will test this?  I don't need a provably correct algorithm - a probabilistic/empirical test would be fine.  If $S_1 \neq S_2$ I would like to be able to produce a specific counterexample.

Comment: My first association was to use some modified Buchberger algorithm.  Apparently [this](http://sunsite.informatik.rwth-aachen.de/Publications/AIB/2013/2013-08.pdf) paper tries to do such a thing but I find it rather opaque.  It may contain other interesting pointers though.

Answer (score 2):

I think one should be able to do this using Cylindrical Algebraic Decomposition (CAD). You can find an introduction in "Algorithms in real algebraic geometry" by Basu, Pollack and Roy. This algorithm is also implemented in [Mathematica](https://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CylindricalDecomposition.html).

Comment: That looks like what I need, thanks!

Comment: Indeed, you can do this using CAD. With the notation of the question : let $\mathcal{F} = \{f_1,...,f_s\}$ the set of all polynomials defining your sets $S_1$ and $S_2$. We assume each $f_i$ to have rational coefficients. Build a CAD that is $\mathcal{F}-$invariant. You will obtain a set of point $\{p_1,...,p_t\} \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. Check if every point $p_i \in S_1$ (resp. $S_1$) is in $S_2$ (resp. $S_1$). It's true iff $S_1 = S_2$.